# How to serve reactive ByteChunks in Play Framework (Java) v2.4.x

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, reactive-programming

I have a working code base that serves `Chunks<byte[]>` wrapped in an HTTP status [206](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.7). The code streams an .mp3 file to the browser.

```
public class ChunksController extends Controller {

    private static byte[] song;
    private static RangeWrapper range;
    private static Chunks<byte[]> chunks;

    @With(MP3Headers.class)
    public static F.Promise<Result> handler() {
        return F.Promise.promise(new Function0<Result>() {
            public Result apply() throws Throwable {

                // Now we are serving a Promise of a Result
                // Is there a way to serve a Promise of Chunks<byte[]>?

                song = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("public/mp3/song.mp3"));
                range = new RangeWrapper(request().getHeader("Range"), song.length);

                chunks = new ByteChunks() {
                    public void onReady(Chunks.Out<byte[]> out) {
                        out.write(Arrays.copyOfRange(song, range.getFrom(), range.getTo()));
                        out.close();
                    }
                };

                // Set response headers so that the browser knows the content
                response().setHeader("Content-Range", String.format("bytes %d-%d/%d", range.getFrom(), range.getTo(), song.length));
                response().setHeader("X-Content-Length", Integer.toString(range.getContentLength()));
                response().setHeader("Content-Length", Integer.toString(range.getContentLength()));

                // I am very much wondering if this is the blocking part of the program...
                return status(206, chunks);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the code example, `MP3Headers` and `RangeWrapper` are convenience classes, defined below.

```
public class MP3Headers extends Action.Simple {

    public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        ctx.response().setContentType("audio/mpeg");
        ctx.response().setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
}
```

And `RangeWrapper` that just stores the from and to that were requested.

```
public class RangeWrapper {

    private int from;
    private int to;

    public RangeWrapper(String range, int totalLength) {
        // check range header for content
        if (range != null) {
            String[] intermediary = range.split("=")[1].split("-");
            this.from = Integer.parseInt(intermediary[0]);

            if (intermediary.length > 1) {
                this.to = Integer.parseInt(intermediary[1]);
            } else {
                this.to = totalLength - 1;
            }
        } else {

            this.from = 0;
            this.to = totalLength - 1;
        }
    }


    /** Getters */
    public int getFrom() {
        return this.from;
    }

    public int getTo() {
        return this.to;
    }

    public int getContentLength() {
        return this.to - this.from + 1;
    }
}
```

Now for the actual problem. The amount of instances that can be processed by the Play Server seems to be very limited, I think this has to do with the synchronous nature of `ByteChunks`. In the image below you can see that only five requests are being satisfied with data. The rest seems to not getting any content. Does someone have a solution to this problem?

[image: Only five simultanious streams can be handled.]

Regards, Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getContentLength` method is incorrect, because it returns negative lengths:

```
MP3 size = 12000
from = 0
to = 5000
getContentLength = -4999
```

Fix this method and it should work.

Apart from that, you should note that `range` and `chunks` are static fields, and you may face concurrency problems. Also in Play controllers are asynchronous by default, so I think wrapping your code in a promise is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the getContentLength() mistake! As for the static fields, I'm going to test it today and will come back to accepting your answer.